# Validation code only checks the first item?

Tags: ios, swift, string, validation, uitextfield

I am creating an app using Swift where I need to validate a form before submitting the form. Right now I have a nested if/else statement attached to the "Save" button inside of IBAction where if it sees that the first input in empty i.e. Name, that "Name" label turns red and gets an *, signaling the user must enter that information before continuing. However, I have reached a bug where it only checks the first input and turns it red (if empty), even if the whole page is empty.

How can I more effectively build this validation code so that it checks all values before turning items red and just the first item.

```
`if (Name!.text!.isEmpty) {
            nameLabel.text = "Name *"
            nameLabel.textColor = UIColor.red
        } else {
            if (Date!.text!.isEmpty) {
                dateLabel.text = "Outage Event ID *"
                dateLabel.textColor = UIColor.red
            } `
```

This is longer but I didn't see the need to add all of them so these are the first two nested if/else statements.

Comment: Do you want to show the alert for all the fields that are empty?

Comment: Yes. Ideally I would like the user to be aware that a field is empty.

Comment: If all the fields are mandatory you can use && operator too to check and validate wether you have data in all of the required field. This will require only one if-else and all your data will be validated.

Comment: Your question helped me so much with my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all follow the proper `naming rules for variables`,

1. don't use `keywords` as `variable` names. `Date` is a keyword. Use `date` or `dateField` or something else instead.
2. name the variables with first letter as a small instead of a capital one, i.e. `name` instead of `Name`.

Instead of using nested `if` statements, use multiple `if` statements to check for all fields, i.e.

```
if let text = name?.text, text.isEmpty {
    nameLabel.text = "Name *"
    nameLabel.textColor = UIColor.red
}

if let text = date?.text, text.isEmpty {
    dateLabel.text = "Outage Event ID *"
    dateLabel.textColor = UIColor.red
}
```

Comment: Nitpick - `Date` is not a keyword. `if` and `while` are keywords. `Date` is just a name of a struct. Your point is valid of course. Avoid using existing class/struct/enum names for your own types and variables.

Comment: My last entry is a textView and not a textField called categoryNotes and that one doesn't respond to this (or to the code I had before) do you have any advice?

Comment: A `textView` also has the `text` property that you can check for `isEmpty` state the same way.

Answer (score 0):

If you nest with If/else(s) it will only run one of them (in case all are empty)

In your example name is already empty so it executes your if code and discard the elses.

You should do one if for each check you wanna do, if they are many you can save some lines of code like this:

```
for textField in [nameTextField, dateTextField, etc] {
   if textField.isEmpty {
      textField.textColor = .red
      textField.text.append(" *")
   }
}
```

Of course that way works good for the color but not that good for the * in case you want to not just append but modify it like I guess you're doing in the case of Date.